# VS2015 Designer View loading System.Exception 0x8e5e0408

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, designer

I am running VS2015 Community on Windows 10 Pro, Iope recently renamed my C:\Users[username] folder and then replaced all keys that I could in the registry. All the other application work fine but when I opened a previously made C# Windows Phone 8.1 project, the designer failed to load and return System.Exceptino error, with error code 0x8e5e0408. (This error appears at newly created projects too)

Below is the log:

> System.Exception
>   Install failed. Please contact your software vendor.
>   Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package App.ab0c2d672.a4da1.a4632.a8d73.a0b9975e092b4_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (AppXManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x8E5E0408. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Thank you!

Comment: Try re-installing Visual Studio, and then realize that you probably did more damage than good by renaming your profile that way. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/rename-user-account-folder-in-windows-10-preview/88033eca-6b32-47c5-90ac-a5e7af17d094?auth=1

Comment: Yep, done that, didn't work. Sorry. (And that's the only way to rename a user folder isn't it?)

Comment: The link i gave is how you do it.

Comment: That is exactly how I did it, even same link I used. Also not related to the question.